# Consulta MySQL - [id's] separados por coma

Tags: mysql, join

Tengo dos tablas: la tabla A tiene ciertos campos, entre ellos su llave primaria `Id`; en el desarrollo tienen la tabla B con un campo con el cual se encuentra relacionada la tabla A (conceptualmente, ya que no existe una relación creada en la base de datos).

En ciertos registros de B, el campo `id_Item_A` tiene diferentes id separados por coma (el desarrollo está así y no puedo cambiarlo). Quisiera saber si hay forma de hacer un `INNER JOIN` que me trajera los campos de los Id de A que estén en B.

```
Tabla A:
******************
**|id|***|Item |**
******************
**|1 |***|item1|**
**|2 |***|item2|**
**|3 |***|item3|**

Tabla B:
********************************
**|id***|id_Item_A|***|elemento|
********************************
**|1 |***|  1,2   |***|elemento1|
**|2 |***|  2,3   |***|elemento2|
**|3 |***|  1,3   |***|elemento3|
```

Este es el ejemplo para las tablas que tengo. Entonces, quisiera saber si es posible hacer un `INNER JOIN` y que, por ejemplo, en el `elemento2` me dijera que está relacionado con `Item2` e `Item3`.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿El 'id_Item_A' de la tabla 'B' es una foranea de la tabla 'A'?

Comment: Si señor. indica con que Ids de la tabla A se encuentra Relacionados

Comment: Ok, ¿cuando vas a  guardar los datos en la tabla B si tes lo guarda con relacion a la tabla A?....

Comment: No, la base de datos no está relacionada, es por eso que lo mencioné como "conceptualmente" , como usuario se que hay esa relación pero no existen esas relaciones en la base de datos definidas

Comment: Tendria que saber un poco mas de que manera estas desarrollando la base de datos, si por consola o por medio de 'graficos' pero  lo que si te puedo decir y que depronto te va ayudar es lo siguiente: Si en la tabla A tienes un  ID con int pues en la tabla B has una foranea con el nombre que tu quieras pero con el mismo dato es decir, id_Item_A con dato INT tu no puedes trabajar con un ID 1 en la tabla A y almancer en la table B un ID 1,2...pues no estarias haciendo ninguna relacion ya que la tabla B deberia de tomar el mismo valor de la tabla A espero me hayas entendido...Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Con la función `FIND_IN_SET (search string, string list)` podrías conseguirlo, quedaría algo así:

```
select * from TABLAA tblA inner join TABLAB tblB on 0 != 

FIND_IN_SET(tblA.id, tblB.id_Item_A)
```

Lo que hace esta función es buscar un string en una lista de string, devolviendo la posición en la que se encuentra dentro de la lista y devolviendo **0** en caso de no encontrarlo.

Comment: debiera ser más bien `FIND_IN_SET(tblA.id, tblB.id_Item_A)`

Comment: Efectivamente, la fuí haciendo en caliente y no me fijé bien, lo corrijo ahora.