# JOINS con cadenas delimitadas por coma

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla que se llama USERS, los cuales tienen un índice de ciertas nacionalidades como una cadena delimitada por comas.

```
ID | NOMBRE | NACIONALIDAD
1  | JUAN   | 1,2,3
2  | PEDRO  | 1,2
3  | JOSE   | 1,3
```

Tengo mi tabla de NACIONALIDADES

```
ID | NACION
1  | Ruso
2  | Español
3  | Brasileño
```

¿Cómo podría hacer el INNER JOIN para que me traiga los nombres? Intenté con:

```
SELECT U.* FROM USERS U INNER JOIN NACIONALIDADES N ON U.NACIONALIDAD IN ( N.ID )
```

Espero una salida así como

```
ID | NOMBRE | NACIONALIDAD
1  | JUAN   | Ruso,Español,Brasileño
2  | PEDRO  | Ruso,Español
3  | JOSE   | Ruso,Brasileño
```

Estoy usando PHP, podría primero obtener un arreglo inicial de nacionalidades y luego comparar los índices, pero me gustaría saber si existe una consulta directa con la base de datos.

Gracias

Comment: Intenta al revez `SELECT U.* FROM USERS U INNER JOIN NACIONALIDADES N ON N.ID IN ( U.NACIONALIDAD )`

Comment: Uff, ya he intentado lo que comenta @alanfcm pero sólo devuelve la primera coincidencia. Yo optaría por normalizar y crear una tabla intermedia, porque aunque se consiga de alguna manera va a estar siempre dando la lata. Además la tabla intermedia permitiría agregar más información útil como cual es la nacionalidad de origen,  la fecha en que obtiene la nacionalidad si la tenemos, etc.

Comment: Si, hay N cantidad de soluciones, pero quería ver si hay algo con SQL que me ayude a hacer estas tareas más fáciles sin intervenir más infraestructura u otro lenguaje

Comment: dado el escenario planteado, no resultaría mas factible una relación de muchos a muchos con una tabla usuario, nacionalidad y una llamada usuario_nacionalidad; donde va a ser mas fácil manejar a una persona con múltiples nacionalidades?

Comment: es un caso parecido a este https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/165794/81450

Comment: y aquí uno mas antiguo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/50955/81450

Comment: Ha y ya lo había preguntado yo mismo. Curiosa mente que tengo, gracias alo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estamos de acuerdo en que será necesario *normalizar* tu situación.

No obstante tu pregunta me pareció curiosa, así que intenté una solución. De hecho, se puede lograr lo que quieres usando **[`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)**.

La consulta sería así:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(n.nacion ORDER BY n.nacion) naciones  
FROM users_20180702 u 
INNER JOIN nacionalidades_20180702 n 
    ON FIND_IN_SET(n.nacion_id,u.nacionalidad)
GROUP   BY u.user_id;
```

Y el resultado:

```
user_id       nombre        naciones
-------------------------------------
1             JUAN          BR,ES,RU
2             PEDRO         ES,RU
3             JOSÉ          BR,RU
```

Observa que yo he aplicado un `ORDER BY` dentro del `GROUP_CONCAT` para que me dé la lista de naciones ordenadas. Si te interesa en cualquier orden lo puedes quitar.

---

### Demo

Aquí puedes ver un <kbd>**[DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/OBR28328)**</kbd>.

Comment: Gracias, curiosamente ya lo había preguntado y ni me acordaba.

Answer (score 2):

Si es `Mysql`, puedes usar

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(string SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

Si es `SQLServer` `XML PATH`

```
SELECT
     [User], Activity,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + PageURL
          FROM TableName
          WHERE [User] = a.[User] AND Activity = a.Activity
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS URLList
FROM TableName AS a
GROUP BY [User], Activity
```

Postgres también tiene uno

```
SELECT company_id, string_agg(employee, ', ')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Comment: Entiendo el group_concat, pero como implementaría esa parte con el JOIN, ya me perdí ahí.

Comment: Necesitas hacer el inner join como lo estás haciendo, esto te va a traer registros duplicados por cada nacionalidad, así que a esa query es a la que le haces el Group By, @a-cedano ya te la hizo específica