# ¿concatenar una misma columna en consulta?

Tags: c#, sql

Primero que nada lo siento por saber usar todas las herramientas disponibles.. intentare enseñarlos como puedo..

tengo esta consulta:

```
   Nombre    Clase    Raza      Contexto
   Lazaro    Burlón   Humano    Lazaro es un ...
   Lazaro    Barbaro  Humano    Lazaro es un ...
   Quintin   Paladin  Orco      QUintin es un ...
   tiruriru  Bardo    Elfo      Tiruriru es un ...
```

Vale entonces tengo el problema de que cargo un datagridview con la consulta que me devuelve eso.. y me duplica, triplica, cuadriplica (depende de la cantidad de clases) algunos personajes.
He intentado mil formas, pero estoy aprendiendo y me siento muy frustrado.. alguien me puede ayudar a que quede de tal manera que no se dupliquen personajes.. es decir:

```
  Nombre     Clase                       Raza      Contexto
  Lazaro     Burlón, Barbaro             Humano    Lazaro es un ...
  Quintin    Paladin                     Orco      QUintin es un ...
  tiruriru   Bardo                       Elfo      Tiruriru es un ...
  tinkiwinki Bardo,Guerrero, caballero   Gnomo     Tinkiwinki es un ...
```

añado la query aunque no se si es asi :S:

```
string command = string.Format(select p.nombre Nombre, c.nombre Clase, p.nivel Nivel, r.nombre Raza, p.descripcion_historia Contexto, 
p.descripcion_personalidad Personalidad from jugador j inner join 
jugador_personaje jp on j.id_jugador = jp.id_jugador inner join personaje p 
on p.id_personaje = jp.id_personaje inner join personaje_clases pc on 
p.id_personaje = pc.id_personaje inner join clases c on pc.id_clase = 
c.id_clase inner join raza r on p.id_raza = r.id_raza where j.nombre = 
'{0}'", this.usuario);
```

Esquema DDL

```
CREATE TABLE Personajes
    (`id_personaje` int(11), `Nombre` varchar(20));

INSERT INTO Personajes
    (`id_personaje`,`Nombre`)
VALUES
    (1,'Lazaro'),
    (2,'Quintin'),
    (3,'Tiruriru');

CREATE TABLE Clases
(`id_clase` int(11), `Nombre` varchar(20));

INSERT INTO Clases
    (`id_clase`,`Nombre`)
VALUES
    (1,'Burlón'),
    (2,'Caballero'),
    (3,'Barbaro'),
    (4,'Paladin'),
    (5,'Bardo');
CREATE TABLE clases_personajes
(id_personaje int(11), id_clase int(11));

INSERT INTO clases_personajes
    (id_personaje, id_clase)
VALUES
  (1,1),(1,3),(2,4), (3,2),(3,5);
```

Comment: Hola Yosi, no has puesto la consulta ¿no?

Comment: Cierto ya la añadí graicas

Comment: Pues no doy con ninguna solución por ahora pero dejo un esquema simplificado del problema en la misma pregunta por si alguien está más inspirado que yo, mañana sigo.

Answer (score 1):

Para juntar esas columnas tienes dos opciones, una es obtener los resultados y luego procesarlos en el código, más sencillo y limpio, aunque pues te traerías datos de más:

```
var groupedResults = list.GroupBy(jugador => jugador.Nombre)
    .ToDictionary(keyValue => keyValue.Key, keyValue => keyValue.ToList());
foreach (var keyValuePair in groupedResults)
{
    var classesAsString =
        string.Join(", ", keyValuePair.Value.Select(jugador => jugador.Clase));
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"El jugador {keyValuePair.Key} tiene las clases {classesAsString}");
}
```

Con esto agrupas los resultados en un diccionado donde tienes a todos, puedes recorrer el diccionario para sacar los datos

Otra forma es usar el `FOR XML PATH ('')` de SqlServer junto con un `Group By`, así al final de tu query puedes poner el Group By por nombre y concatenar las clases en una columna de tu elección

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp_name,
STUFF(
(SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(proj_id)
FROM project_members AS t1 
WHERE t1.emp_name = t2.emp_name
FOR XML PATH (''))
, 1, 1, '')
FROM project_members t2
```

Si tienes dudas checa la documentación de `FOR XML PATH`

Si no estás usando SQL Server puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177378/joins-con-cadenas-delimitadas-por-coma/177395#177395) para otras DBs

Comment: Guau, que maravilla, años con SQL y no conocía estas funciones. Gracias!

Comment: muchisimas gracias voy a probarlo ahora mismo